# Getting undefined store in quasar

Tags: vue.js, quasar

I have a folder called functions under src in the same level as store

below code is from account/index.js

```
import store from 'src/store/index.js'
export async function abc () {
console.log(store.state) //prints undefined
  store.commit('account/updateToken', 'asdas')
}
```

I am getting below error on this code

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: src_store_index_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_11__.default.commit is not a function
```

Is there anything I am missing on how to import store to a .js file?

Comment: did you try change import store from 'src/store/index.js' to import store from '@/store/index.js'

Comment: @NgocTuanLam Yes, i get the same error

Answer (score 0):

did you define the store in

```
store/index.js
```

you have to

```
import myStoreName from './myStoreFolderName'
```

and then in the module section add your store

```
modules: {
  myStoreName,
```